Spring Gateway with authenticator not forwarding requests
I am quite new to using Spring Gateway and I am setting it up with Spring Gateway MVC as I did my authentication in MVC. I have added the dependencies to my pom, I have an API running in port 8090. I want all requests that reach the gateway with the prefix /api/** be redirected to the API.
Here is my .yaml config for the redirect:
spring:
 cloud:
  gateway:
    mvc:
      routes:
        - id: backend
          uri: http://localhost:8090
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/**
            - Method=GET,POST
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1

However, this is not working, when I call my endpoint via http://localhost:8088/api/{endpoint} I have:

404 - NOT FOUND

But I am sure this endpoint exists.
Am I missing something, is there a way to debug this?
Also, I have some questions related to what I am doing. I had planned to create this gateway for 2 purposes:

Serve as the project gateway;
Take care of the authentication step for every request.

My purpose would be that if a request is correctly authenticated it should forward the request to the API, if not it gives the appropriate error.
Can/should this be done?
How can I make use of the JWT token I pass from the gateway to the API to enable MethodSecurity in the API? If I add the security of Spring it will automatically redirect me to the login page so I wanted to ask if this is possible.

Hey, Actually I found it! I am using a applicaiton.yaml-dev and the generic one had a classpath that I needed to add. So with that in the call it no longer shows the 404-Not found, thanks for the help! Regarding the other questions, do you have any insight?

@JAsgarov Looks like mvc is correct, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/appendix.html

@dur yeah, funny, I use gateway at work, and we always defined it without mvc, as well as this example of the filter OP uses is without mvc. But you are right, that exists as well, will have to look into what the difference is

@learningProgrammer reg other points it is a bit too broad to answer here, but yes, that is one of primary uses of gateway, to centralize cross cutting concerns like authentication, so totally fair use

@learningProgrammer Do not write multiple questions in one question. Also do not write too broad questions. Both are reasons to close your question. More over, your application.yaml problem looks like a typo / not reproducable and could be closed soon.
